# I can't resolve this issue despite attempting numerous times. All elements are clearly defined, imported, and declared, yet the problem persists

Tags: node.js, angular

✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-register' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-register' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-register' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

   src/app/app.component.html:5:0:
   5 │ 
   ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

```
src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
  5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

i want to make signup ,sign-in page using (Node and Angular)

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router'; 

@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-root', 
    standalone: true, 
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet], 
    templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
    styleUrl: './app.component.css' 
}) 
export class AppComponent { title = 'frond-end'; }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { routes } from './app.routes'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component'; 
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component'; 
import { ContactUsComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, RegisterComponent, ContactUsComponent,],
    imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), FormsModule, HttpClientModule,],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
}) export class AppModule { }
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { ContactUsComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { RegisterComponent } from "./register/register.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: ContactUsComponent, },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, }
];
```

Comment: @AnsSajid please share more details, is the `appComponent` stand alone, we need to see the code, if you are using app module, please share that also!

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @NarenMurali 

here is my app.component.html

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" class="form-control" id="stname" placeholder="Enter Email" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Passwor

Comment: @Muhammad I require the `app.component.ts` `app.module.ts` `app.routing.module.ts`

Comment: app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frond-end';
}

Comment: app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ContactUsComponent } from './home/home.component';

Comment: @NgModule({
  
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ContactUsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

Comment: app.routes.ts

import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { ContactUsComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { RegisterComponent } from "./register/register.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  
  {
  path: 'home',
  component: ContactUsComponent,
  
  },
  {

  path: 'register',
  component: RegisterComponent,
  }
];

Answer (score 0):

`App.component.ts` is using standalone so we cannot use modules for routing and imports, so here is a stackblitz highlighting how to integrate using the new standalone way.

Do go through the documentation for new standalone methodology, references below!

[standalone docs](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components)

[standalone article](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/comprehensive-guide-to-angular-standalone-components#:%7E:text=The%20official%20Angular%20documentation%2C%20for,style%20without%20any%20breaking%20changes.%E2%80%9D)

---

main.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'zone.js';
import { routes } from './routes';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientModule, RegisterComponent, RouterModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ title }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-register></app-register>
  `,
})
export class App {
  title = 'frond-end';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient()],
});
```

routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
];
```

example component!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

`provideRouter` -> angular 17 way of initializing routing for standalone

`provideHttpClient` -> angular 17 way of initializing httpClient for making API calls in standalone

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jvdgwm?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Froutes.ts,src%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts,src%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts,src%2Fregister%2Fregister.component.ts,src%2Findex.html&title=Angular%20Starter)